# Check device type?

Tags: apache-flex, device

- Is it possible, and how ( if it is ) to check the device type with flex ?

*with device type i mean : PC, laptop, tablet, phone ..*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Start with the `flash.system.Capabilities` class.   [Link to Flex SDK docs about Capabilities](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/system/Capabilities.html#includeExamplesSummary)
Check the `.os` property.

From there, you might also need to check [flash.system.TouchscreenType](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/system/TouchscreenType.html)

Eventually, though, to get very detailed info about the device, installing WURFL on the server side may be your best bet.

http://wurfl.sourceforge.net/

Comment: an useful link to nice library +1 :)